# Overflow: visible not working

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

My logo disappears when I horizontally shrink my browser window (so, mobile phone view).

http://zanifesto.com

I set the css to overflow:visible, but it doesn't make a difference.

My goal is to have the narrow (mobile) format be a vertical stacking of header, register/login, and then "Create something new".

Any suggestions?

```
.gbtr_tools_info {
color:#b39964;
font-size:10px;
text-transform:uppercase;
padding:5px 0;
overflow:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this line in your CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 719px)
.gbtr_tools_info {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change `overflow:visible` to `overflow:auto`

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
overflow:visible !important
```

Seems to get overriden by js.